# Change WebRole binding in runtime

Tags: azure, binding, runtime

We are using a single WebRole to host multiple WebSites. My application changes pictures and other stuffs based on the site url, let's call this 'Plataform'.
   This is my configuration.

```
Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1"
hostHeader="mysite.domain.com" 

Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1"
hostHeader="anothersite.domain.com"
```

When I need another binding (another plataform) today I have to publish my entire WebRole again. Is there a way to add this binding at runtime?

I'm using Azure Sdk 2.5

Comment: Found something using ServerManager but still getting COM Exception (Class not registered).
Does anybody knows if it's possible to add this using WorkerRole?